# DynamicData: use custom type as return type

Tags: dynamic-data, dbml

can I force the DBML designer to use my custom types instead of the Auto-generated Types?
I can edit the database.designer.cs, but these changes will be lost when I modify the tables.

If not, how can I easily "convert" from the auto-generated type to my custom type in Linq?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The DBML designer is code-gen, plain and simple - although the dml may help as the mapping file

There are various options here:

- use SqlMetal to generate the mapping file
- decorate your existing objects with the standard attributes
- use an external xml file to describe the relationships

Resources:

- [External Mapping Reference (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386907.aspx)
- [LINQ In Action](http://www.manning.com/marguerie/) describes both options.
- [Using LINQ to SQL XML Mapping Files – Step by Step](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/08/18/using-linq-to-sql-xml-mapping-files-step-by-step.aspx)

Note also that EF in 4.0 also supports POCO.

---

If you just want to manually project from the LINQ type to your type; if they have similar properties, something like `PropertyCopy` in [MiscUtil](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/miscutil/) may help - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/531505/how-to-copy-value-from-class-x-to-class-y-with-the-same-property-name-in-c/531507#531507).