# Cloning the WebBrowser Control in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

Is it possible to clone the WebBrowser control in C#? By clone, I mean, all the properties, and everything? Haven't really been able to find to much on this online. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: May I know why do you want to clone? Why not extend?

Comment: You can try serializing and the deserialize the control.

Comment: Well, here is emit mapper discussion, might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3457657/object-copy-approaches-in-net-auto-mapper-emit-mapper-implicit-operation-pr

Comment: @whihathac Sorry if there is some confusion. I come from a Java background. When I say clone, I mean return a non shallow copy of the object.

Comment: @SamFisher83 I thought about that. Wasnt curious if that would work or not. Thought there might be a cleaner way to do it. But def worth a shot.